# Multiple loops over the same Generator - PHP

Tags: php, yield, php-generators

I need to loop over the same generator over multiple loops - I have tried to use rewind be I get this error - "Cannot rewind a generator that was already run".

```
$gen = myGenerator();
while ($gen->valid()){
    $document = $gen->current();
    $gen->next();
    //...
}

$gen->rewind(); //this is where i get the error

while ($gen->valid()){
    $document = $gen->current();
    $gen->next();
    //...
}
```

Comment: This isn't what generators are for--they can only be exhausted once. Does your data fit into memory? If so, convert the generator to an array. If not, consider calling `myGenerator()` a second time.

Comment: This is the problem - my data is too large to fit.. Converting into an array is not an option..

Comment: Can you call `myGenerator()` again? If not (presumably because `$document`s are stateful and being updated), you'll need to provide more details in the question about what you're doing here.

Comment: $document is a mongodb cursor - so technically I can do a query again but I'm not sure it is the best thing to do since my queries are complex.

Comment: If it's retrieving so much data that it doesn't fit in memory, the cost of calling the query is amortized across all that work and likely insignificant. I'd just call `myGenerator` again and profile the code. In the event that there is a problem, as I mentioned, there'll need to be some special information provided that can help shed light on possible optimization options, because you've already stated that keeping it in memory (i.e. caching it) is not possible.

Comment: Yes I will do sum tests and will check the impact of DB performance while doing multiple queries like that. Thank you for your answer!